# pthread_join(thread_id, &res) , if &res is not NULL - is free(res) needed?

Tags: linux, pthreads, pthread-join

I've stumbled across a code example [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). The lines that caught my attention (all other lines skipped):

```
{  
...  
void *res;  
...  
s = pthread_join(tinfo[tnum].thread_id, &res);  
...  
free(res);      /* Free memory allocated by thread */  
}
```

Can anyone deeper into pthreads than myself comment on the `free(res)`, please? I have to say I have never seen this before, and that googling for 1-1.5 hours didn't give me any other similar examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In pthread_join(thread_id, &res) , if &res is not NULL - is free(res)
>   needed?

It depends whether the return value of thread was dynamically allocated (with `malloc()` & co).

If you look at the function `thread_start()` on same page, you'll see that it has a return statement:

```
return uargv;
```

and `uagrv` was allocated with:

```
       uargv = strdup(tinfo->argv_string);
```

Hence, the `free()` call is used in `main()` after the `pthread_join()` call.
Because `res` is the filled with `uargv` (returned by the thread). You can conceptually assume there's a code  like this inside `pthread_join()` function:

```
 if (res)
   *res = uargv;
```

Here's it's allocated using [`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) (which internally allocates memory). So you `free()` it. If the thread simply has `return NULL;` (and free()'s the `uargv` itself) then you don't need `free()`.

The general answer is if you allocate something with `malloc()` family functions then you need to `free()`.

Comment: deleted, fighting with the engine ;)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I missed the strdup() (or, rather, auto-converted it to alloca() while reading, though alloca() is not allowed to be used for this purpose).   You actually gave me a new direction in thinking...  I somehow assumed that once a thread is (correctly) terminated its resources are freed automatically by the system (with a few explicitly mentioned in man-pages exclusions).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I missed the strdup().   You actually gave me a new direction in thinking.  I somehow assumed that once a thread is (correctly) terminated its resources are freed automatically by the system (with a few explicitly mentioned in man-pages exceptions).:  "If a thread is joinable, then another thread can call pthread_join(3) to wait for the thread to terminate and fetch its exit status.  Only when a terminated joinable thread has been joined are the last of its resources released back to the system."

Comment: @A.Toumantsev `I somehow assumed that once a thread is (correctly) terminated its resources are freed automatically by the system` - No. But it's true for a *process* termination (this is true on modern operating systems -- but there can be systems such as some embedded platforms where as explicit free() is required to reclaim the memory even on process exit).

Comment: @A.Toumantsev: Memory allocated with `malloc()` (or the equivalent, like `strdup()`) is not a resource belonging to the thread - it belongs to the entire process.  Resources belonging to the thread are things like the thread's stack.

Comment: Yep, thanks guys, things are getting much clearer now. [don't know how to 'Vote' for the answer or whatever else people are supposed to do here].

Comment: @A.Toumantsev You need 15 rep to upvote any post. So,unfortunately  you can't do it yet! But thanks for thinking of upvoting :)